# How can I generate an array of PSCustomObjects from an array of hashes in Powershell v3?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Suppose I have an array of hashes in Powershell v3:

```
> $hashes = 1..5 | foreach { @{Name="Item $_"; Value=$_}}
```

I can convert a single hash into a `PSCustomObject` like this:

```
> $co = [PSCustomObject] $hashes[0]
> $co | ft -AutoSize

Value Name  
----- ----  
    1 Item 1

> $co.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object
```

So far, so good. The problem occurs when I try to convert the entire hash array into `PSCustomObjects` in a pipeline:

```
> ($hashes | foreach { [PSCustomObject] $_})[0].getType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     -------- 
True     True     Hashtable                                System.Object
```

As you see, I'm getting an array of `Hashtable` objects, not `PSCustomObjects`. Why do I get different behavior, and how can I accomplish what I want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have yet to figure out the exact cause (Everyone is still learning something) but your issue is related to the `$_` pipe element somehow. I can make your code work if I force a cast of the `$_`

```
$hashes = 1..5 | foreach { @{Name="Item $_"; Value=$_}}
$hashes | %{([pscustomobject][hashtable]$_)}
```

**Output**

```
Value Name  
----- ----  
    1 Item 1
    2 Item 2
    3 Item 3
    4 Item 4
    5 Item 5
```

**Something curious**

I didn't like `Name` and `Value`, while I was testing (That is what a literal hash table had for headers and I found it confusing while I was testing), so I changed the later to `Data` and then the output differs. I only post it as it is curious. It is hard to show the results in the post.

```
Name                                                                                                                                                     Data
----                                                                                                                                                     ----
Item 1                                                                                                                                                      1
Item 2                                                                                                                                                      2
Item 3                                                                                                                                                      3
Item 4                                                                                                                                                      4
Item 5                                                                                                                                                      5
```

Comment: Yep, the [hashtable] cast does the trick. I'd love to know why that's needed.

Comment: I dug this out of the documentation, and it may provide a clue:A base object of type PSCustomObject tells the Windows PowerShell runtime that the encapsulating PSObject object has no meaningful base object. However, this type of encapsulating PSObject object does provide a type name property bag that cmdlet developers can add extended members to. Developers can also specify the type name of the object, which allows this object to share its extended members with other PSObject objects of the same type name.

Comment: I get different results when I set Data="$_".  It seems to display strings differently from ints.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of casting, try calling `New-Object` directly:

```
# > ($hashes | foreach { New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $_})[0].getType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                  
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                  
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object
```

Also, oddly, this seems to work:

```
# > (0..4 |  foreach { ([PSCustomObject]$hashes[$_])})[0].GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                  
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                  
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object
```

Why? I have no idea, it seems to have trouble performing the cast using a pipelined hashtable entry.

Comment: You second approach is similar to the findings in the ops question when he called `$hashes[0]`

Comment: The New-Object workaround works. So does Matt's [hashtable] cast. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
$hashes = 1..5 | foreach { @{Name="Item $_"; Value=$_}}

foreach ($hash in $hashes)
{([PSCustomObject]$hash).gettype()}
```

Comment: In this case, you're using the foreach language construct. Inside a pipeline, 'foreach' is treated as an alias for the ForEach-Object command. See the about_Foreach help topic.

Comment: @David - I know it's a foreach loop.  I wasn't aware that it had to be a pipeline solution, or given that the hash table collection is already resident in memory, any particular advantage in doing it that way.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that value of pipeline variable `$_` get wrapped into `PSObject` and that break cast to `PSCustomObject`.

```
> $hashes=@{Value=1},[PSObject]@{Value=2}

> $hashes[0].GetType().FullName
System.Collections.Hashtable
> $hashes[1].GetType().FullName
System.Collections.Hashtable
# It seems that both $hashes elements are Hashtable,

> [Type]::GetTypeArray($hashes).FullName
System.Collections.Hashtable
System.Management.Automation.PSObject
# But, as you can see, second one is not.

> ([PSCustomObject]$hashes[0]).GetType().FullName
System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
> ([PSCustomObject]$hashes[1]).GetType().FullName
System.Collections.Hashtable
# And that difference break cast to PSCustomObject.
```

Comment: You are always around for casting and typing questions :)